# How to receive SMS using AT Commands

Tags: vb.net, at-command

I want to receive an SMS but I don't know how to get the text message please check my code.

```
Dim receivedData, smsMode as String
smsMode = vbCrLf

port.Write("AT+CNMI=2,1,0,0,1")
Thread.Sleep(1000)
port.Write("AT+CMGR" & smsMode)
Thread.Sleep(1000)
port.Write("AT+CMGL=" & "ALL" & smsMode)
Thread.Sleep(1000)
```

I want to display the new message in my DataGridView. I have no idea what to call like

`receivedData = port.read, readexisting`, etc.

Comment: better off using a library like GSMComm

Comment: i am only a beginner of at commands if i am more knowledgeable of this i am going to try that GSMComm